# connect не связывает сигнал clicked QToolButton помещенного в QGridLayout со slot'ом класса

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

При нажатии на кнопку `QToolButton::clicked` не происходит вызова метода `JCPModelsWidget::onButtonsCliked` ...

Ошибок - как при компиляции, так и при выполнении - никаких нет.
Что то делаю не так но что понять не получается. 
Буду очень благодарен за любые мнения !

```
QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout(this);
        ...
            for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); ++l) {
            QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(l);
               ...
                QIcon icon(fileInfo.filePath());
                QToolButton* button = new QToolButton;
                button->setIcon(icon);
                button->setText(fileInfo.baseName());
                button->setIconSize(QSize(85,85));
                button->setToolButtonStyle (Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
                connect(button, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &JCPModelsWidget::onButtonsCliked);
                grid->addWidget(button,pos_v,pos_h);
                ...
            } // end for l 
        ptrToUI->modelsGroup->setLayout(grid);

void JCPModelsWidget::onButtonsCliked() {
    qDebug() << "Что я делаю не так ? :)";
};

#ifndef JCPMODELS_H
#define JCPMODELS_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <ui_jcp.h>
#include <ads.h>

class JCPModelsWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    JCPModelsWidget(Ui::JCP* _ptrToUI, QString pathToModelsDir, QWidget* parent=nullptr);
    CONDITIONS load(QString pathToModelsDir);
    void errMsg(QString errmsg);
private slots:
    void onButtonsCliked(); 
private:
    Ui::JCP* ptrToUI;
};

#endif // JCPMODELS_H
```

Comment: Очистите и пересоберите проект

Comment: Уже попробовал ранее ! К сожалению это не помогло !!! Что то мне подсказывает что тут проблема не совсем на поверхности !

Comment: Вручную удалить файлы пробовали? Судя по этому коду, должно работать. Grid наполняется в конструкторе? )

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду удаление директории с результатом работы bildera (build-jcp-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug) то да я ее удалял ! Так же я удалял все сохраненные копии файла .pro - но это думаю ни на что влиять не должно ! К моему сожелению это не меняет ситуации !

Comment: Попробуйте также удалить проект, и переписать :)